# Adding Users in Azure AD B2C using Custom Policies

Tags: xml, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-graph-api

I have a scenario in which I want to create custom policies for sign-in and sign-up .For the signup process what I want is that an activation link should be sent to their email (Signup option is not available on the sign in screen). Users have to click that link to go to the signup page and when they have successfully signed up , they will be redirected to the sign in page.

Currently what I have achieved so far is that I am successfully able to signup a user and then sign him in by using the default sign-up sign-in policy in the Azure AD B2C.

So basically the things I want to achieve are, firstly a Custom Sign in policy that just sign-in the user and then a custom policy for sign-up in which when an activation link is sent to their mail the user fills the information and then sign-in.

**What could be the best way to achieve this?**

Answer (score 0):

As per [this](https://medium.com/the-new-control-plane/tips-and-tricks-for-working-with-custom-policies-in-azure-ad-b2c-eb63b508a075),

"There is a custom SignUpOrSignin policy but no Signin only policy.

You can achieve this by setting SignUp to “False”.

```
<Item Key=”setting.showSignupLink”>False</Item>"
```

In terms of the activation, have a look at the "magic link" samples [here](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples).

Comment: I Can't find a place for the Item specified , moreover I downloaded the xml file for the built in SignUp-SignIn policy and tried changing it and then uploading it as a custom policy but It threw some error. @nzpcmad

Comment: Or refer to [this invitation flow](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/invite). This is based on [the custom policy starter pack](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-custom-policy-starterpack). Unfortunately, you can't download, modify, and then upload the built-in flow, this isn't supported.